# Understanding a Position Sensor

Tags: position-sensor

I have a Linear position sensor attached to an outboard motor to provide input to an autopilot. It looks like a linear potentiometer with 3 wires and a shield. It has Red, Green, and Blue wires that connect to the controller. The autopilot is giving an error of motor position sensor failure.

From the controller I read 5v being supplied between the Green and Red wires, Green ground and Red positive. When with the motor straight or sensor barrel half way out the Blue wire reads 5V. Turned all the way one direction (barrel out) it reads 2.2v and all the way the other direction (barrel in) it reads 2.8v.

The voltage readings on the Blue wire as you slide the barrel in or out look fairly linear but as it gets close to the mid point the values jumping around until you get to the mid point where it settles on 5V. I would expect a Linear pot to fail at the mid point since that is where most of the movement is as the autopilot makes lots of small corrections to stay on course.

I was thinking the sensor is just a Linear Potentiometer but that doesn't make sense to me since the wiper voltage (my assumption of Blue wire) starts at 5v with the wiper at mid point and goes lower in both directions. Do they make Linear potentiometers that work this way? Any other suggestions for how this sensor is working or what type of sensor it might be?

Thanks

Comment: The blue wire probably has a high value pullup resistor inside the autopilot unit so that it's able to detect when the sensor is missing or broken.

Comment: I believe you are right. But most probably your linear potentiometer is faulty, I'd try disconnect it from autopilot and check with an ohmmeter. BTW what is the autopilot brand?